# Multi-column or block melt and then pivot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, reshape, melt

I'm struggling with a data reshaping problem. I have data approximately like this (but up to C10 group, with a multi-index I added myself.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('C0',0) : {0:'ID1', 1:'ID2', 2:'ID3'},
               ('C0',1) : {0:'ID1', 1:'ID2', 2:'ID3'},
               ('C1',2) : {0:'A'  , 1:'A'  , 2:'A'},
               ('C1',3) : {0:'B'  , 1:'B'  , 2:'B'},
               ('C1',4) : {0:'C'  , 1:'C'  , 2:'C'},
               ('C2',5) : {0:'A'  , 1:'A'  , 2:'A'},
               ('C2',6) : {0:'B'  , 1:'B'  , 2:'B'},
               ('C2',7) : {0:'C'  , 1:'C'  , 2:'C'},
               ('C3',8) : {0:'A'  , 1:'A'  , 2:'A'},
               ('C3',9) : {0:'B'  , 1:'B'  , 2:'B'},
               ('C3',10) : {0:'C'  , 1:'C'  , 2:'C'}
              })

    C0      C1          C2          C3
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   ID1 ID1 A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C
1   ID2 ID2 A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C
2   ID3 ID3 A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C
```

ID columns aren't actually identical values, but the unique key for this data is across multiple columns. Similarly, As, Bs, Cs are not actually identical values, just different types of values. The desired end result is this

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   ID1 ID1 C1  A   B   C
1   ID1 ID1 C1  A   B   C
2   ID1 ID1 C1  A   B   C
3   ID2 ID2 C2  A   B   C
4   ID2 ID2 C2  A   B   C
5   ID2 ID2 C2  A   B   C
6   ID3 ID3 C3  A   B   C
7   ID3 ID3 C3  A   B   C
8   ID3 ID3 C3  A   B   C
```

In messing with this I've gotten to an intermediate point, where I've melted down the first bit, to include both column indexes on a line, but I wasn't able to re-pivot that into the desired format. Ultimately I'll also need to enumerate the lines within the C-groups, but I believe I can do that. First post here, mercy appreciated, but I've checked here and elsewhere to the best of my abilities.

Comment: @Onyambu fantastic and thank you. My toy example didn't translate precisely to with the real data - but your solution absolutely demonstrated the concepts and I was quickly able to adapt it to the real dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could melt then unstack:

```
s = df.melt(id_vars = list(df.columns[:2]), value_vars = list(df.columns[2:]))
d = s.assign(nm = s.groupby(list(s.columns[:3])).cumcount()).drop('variable_1', 1)
d.set_index(list(d.drop('value', 1).columns)).unstack().reset_index()

    C0      variable_0 value      
nm    0    1                0  1  2
0   ID1  ID1         C1     A  B  C
1   ID1  ID1         C2     A  B  C
2   ID1  ID1         C3     A  B  C
3   ID2  ID2         C1     A  B  C
4   ID2  ID2         C2     A  B  C
5   ID2  ID2         C3     A  B  C
6   ID3  ID3         C1     A  B  C
7   ID3  ID3         C2     A  B  C
8   ID3  ID3         C3     A  B  C
```

from hre you can drop the colum levels you want